# retaining the variable label in reshape

Tags: stata

I would like to retain the variable labels after reshaping the dataset from long to wide. I have a problem in inputting the dataset (I keyed them in Excel then imported).

```
clear
set obs 7

input id    a1  a2  a3
"s001"  "John"  23  "Primary"
"s002"  "Mary"  32  "Secondary"
"s002"  "Anna"  23  "Tertiary"
"s003"  "Joseph"    34  "Secondary"
"s003"  "Oganyo"    23  "Primary"
"s004"  "Manyoya"   34  "Tertiary"
"s005"  "Makbuti"   45  "Primary"
end


*======= Label the variables

label var a1 "partners name"
label var a2 "partners age"
label var a3 "partners education"

foreach variable of varlist a*{
    
    local varlabel : variable label `variable'
    di "`varlabel'"

bys id: gen index = _n

renvars a* , postfix(_)


reshape wide a*, i(id) j(index)

label var `variable'* "`varlabel'"

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code here is very confused and just won't work well without major surgery.

At the outset your `input` statement fails to declare string variables when needed.

The `set obs 7` is compatible with an `end` to the `input`.

A big problem is that you are looping over a bunch of commands including `reshape`, but there is just one `reshape` to carry out.

Your code for saving variable labels needs to save then separately.

`renvars` is from the *Stata Journal* (2005), and doesn't seem needed here any way. As from Stata 12 (2011!) it should still work but is essentially superseded by extensions to `rename`.

Here's my best guess at the example you should have given and the code you need.

```
clear

input str4 id   str7 a1  a2  str9 a3
"s001"  "John"  23  "Primary"
"s002"  "Mary"  32  "Secondary"
"s002"  "Anna"  23  "Tertiary"
"s003"  "Joseph"    34  "Secondary"
"s003"  "Oganyo"    23  "Primary"
"s004"  "Manyoya"   34  "Tertiary"
"s005"  "Makbuti"   45  "Primary"
end

label var a1 "partner's name"
label var a2 "partner's age"
label var a3 "partner's education"

local j = 0 
foreach variable of varlist a* { 
    local ++j 
    local varlabel`j' : variable label `variable'
    di "`varlabel`j''"
} 

bys id: gen index = _n 

reshape wide a*, i(id) j(index)

forval j = 1/3 { 
    foreach v of var a`j'* { 
        label var `v' "`varlabel`j''"
    }
}

list 

describe
```

Here's the output of the last two commands.

```
. list 

     +------------------------------------------------------------+
     |   id       a11   a21         a31      a12   a22        a32 |
     |------------------------------------------------------------|
  1. | s001      John    23     Primary              .            |
  2. | s002      Mary    32   Secondary     Anna    23   Tertiary |
  3. | s003    Joseph    34   Secondary   Oganyo    23    Primary |
  4. | s004   Manyoya    34    Tertiary              .            |
  5. | s005   Makbuti    45     Primary              .            |
     +------------------------------------------------------------+

. 
. describe 

Contains data
 Observations:             5                  
    Variables:             7                  
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Variable      Storage   Display    Value
    name         type    format    label      Variable label
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
id              str4    %9s                   
a11             str7    %9s                   partner's name
a21             float   %9.0g                 partner's age
a31             str9    %9s                   partner's education
a12             str7    %9s                   partner's name
a22             float   %9.0g                 partner's age
a32             str9    %9s                   partner's education
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sorted by: id
```

Note: `reshape wide` makes most things more difficult in Stata.

Note: Please use `dataex` to create reproducible data examples in Stata.